# IPTables Remote mySQL Rule

Tags: mysql, iptables

I have a magento web (192.168.148.151) and remote mysql (192.168.140.147) box that im trying to create a rule so that the frontend will talk to the mySQL db

Im using IPTables (ubutun 16.04) Linode

When I disable IPTables I can telnet to the mysql box fine. 
Magento runs fine also.

I would like to enable some rules in IP Tables on the Web Server so only the bare min ports like 80,443,22 are open

On the Web Server, with ip tables disabled I can telnet to the mySQL box
For example:
telnet 192.168.140.147 3306

When I however turn on IPTables my rule doesnt work

Here is my rule

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 192.168.148.151 -d 192.168.140.147 -j ACCEPT
```

How can I communicate from IP:192.168.148.151 to mySQL on IP: 192.168.148.151 using an rule in IPTables?

Regards
Brendan

Comment: You need to 'save' the change in order to stay 'active'. maybe see http://askubuntu.com/questions/119393/how-to-save-rules-of-the-iptables. Took me a few tries before i got it working. it'S a 2-3 step (command) operation alltogether. https://www.howtogeek.com/177621/the-beginners-guide-to-iptables-the-linux-firewall/

Comment: Hi Lousi,

Thanks for reply. Every time I test the rule I run the following cmd to reload

sudo iptables-restore /etc/iptables/rules.v4

Comment: Yes, you need to 'Save' and then 'reload'. From the little i undertand, when you 'INPUT' a new rule it's only kept in memory, so you need to 'write' (save) it before you reload the tables. that why its'input -> save -> reload. hope this helps.